# why the ftp list request return incomplete result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I am developing an app which need to request the document infomation on the server. I use [simpleFTP](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) to request document information, including the name and its modification date. But when the number of document is large, there are always bad document information return:

```
                                               Name   /   Modification                                         
......
2012-06-27 11:22:21.661 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] BOOK 9 / 2012-06-26 07:48:00 +0000
2012-06-27 11:22:21.661 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] Jun 26 15:49 BOOK 90 / (null)   
2012-06-27 11:22:21.661 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] BOOK 91 / 2012-06-26 07:49:00 +0000
2012-06-27 11:22:21.661 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] BOOK 92 / 2012-06-26 07:49:00 +0000
2012-06-27 11:22:21.675 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] BOOK 93 /  2012-06-26 07:49:00 +0000
2012-06-27 11:22:21.612 TestNewFTP[2774:11303] 133 / (null)
```

As the second line shows, the document name turn to be "Jun 26 15:49 BOOK 90" which is actually the modification date and the document name and the modification date turn to be (null). The last line shows more information lost.

What`s more, I find that every time the error happened to the same document.

I want to know why this error happen and is it possible to fix this error?

Comment: Is it possible that this thing just _doesn't_ have a mod date?  Can you quick look it on a Mac?

Comment: @CodaFi It has a right modification date on the server.